# Draw multiple shapes in different views

Tags: android

I created a XML file containing two image view. I want to draw two different circles(different size, color) in the center of each view. How can I do that, especially the coordinates. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that using `shape Drawables` ...

create `circle.xml` in your `Drawable` Folder ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
   <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
   <corners android:radius="12px"/> 
   <stroke  android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000"/> 

</shape>
```

use it in your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/circleimage"  
android:layout_height="150dp" 
android:layout_width="150dp" 
android:src="@drawable/circle">
</ImageView>
```

You can use this circle.xml for one or more imageViews ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of ImageView. Use that subclass in the XML. Then overwrite the

```
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
        super.draw(canvas);
        // do your drawing here
        // canvas holds the drawable area
        // use canvas.drawXXXX methods with basic mathematics to put circles in places you need
   }
```

Hope this answers your question.